# df.Series.value_counts() dtype is int64 when df.Series.dtypes is object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file and one column contains total sales for the day. The data was sometimes entered with punctuation such as `, . ?` either by mistake or just the way of accounting. I am trying to clean up the data. However I noticed when I use `df['Sales'].dtypes` I get `object`, which is the correct data type. However, when I ran value_counts, dtype at the bottom is `int64`.

```
df['Sales'].value_counts(dropna=False)
...
12400 3
12000 1
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

Why did dtype change to int64? Currently the data type should be object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

df.value_counts returns the amount of unique values in the df. This value is a number thus the type: int64. Hope this helped you.